# How to add a listener to a Bitmap in a canvas? ( Android)

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, touch-event

i read in other questions how to get the position of a bitmap and how to define the OnTouchEvent as below but with Bitmap object insn't possible to set a listener,how i have to do?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
int action = event.getAction();
int x = event.getX()  // or getRawX();
int y = event.getY();

switch(action){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
            && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //tada, if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
    }
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to draw the bitmap inside a `View` (e.g. plain `View` and draw `Bitmap` as background or as the source/image of an `ImageView`). Then you can attach an `onTouchListener` to this `View` and do your `onTouchEvent` handling in that listener.

Comment: ...but in this way i can't use canvas

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to do with canvas? In your question, you were just wondering about clicking on the correct spot.

Comment: My class use the onDraw method with canvas and i want to add a listener on a bitmap that it draws

Comment: You mean you override a View's 'public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)' and the 'protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)' methods?